# Database naming, best practise

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, naming-conventions

I have been looking for more than two hours, and i have found many articles about tables/columns naming and other tips, but any exact answer regarding database naming itself. Can you tell me please the best option? And are there some real cases when it makes sense?

1. clothing_store
2. ClothingStore
3. clothingStore
4. or maybe clothing-store

MySQL root user has two default databases named as the first version (information_schema, performance_schema, sys). So it means that the first is best?

Comment: It seems to be the most consistent with mysql. I came from SQL Server environment where everything was shout-case `CLOTHING_STORE`. I think this is wholly about you, your team, and your preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, go with underscores since that's easy to read in upper and lower case. It's also the most commonly used convention in most reference material and existing db's:

> 1. clothing_store

*(And `CLOTHING_STORE`.)*

Most, if not all, DB engines treat table names case-insensitively (even if some *display* them in their original case-sensitive name). So these two are the same:

> 2. ClothingStore
> 3. clothingStore

And so are "Clothingstore", "clothingstore", "CLotHinGstOre", etc.

Table names can't have a hypen, since that's an expression, like `a - b`:

> 4. or maybe clothing-store

You could just call it "`store`", unless you've got multiple tables of different stores.